# Rust - '?' can only be used in a function that returns 'Result'

Tags: function, rust, return

For Reference: I am a Java programmer who is brand new to Rust

I am trying to read a file that has 2 inputs being size of array, and elements of array.

Input:

```
3
1 2 3
```

I want to make a function that reads in a file through arguments in command line so I wrote the following code: (Note: it is super ugly as I was changing up the function)

```
fn getArraySize() -> usize
{
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let input = File::open(&args[1])?;
    let buffered = BufReader::new(input);

    let mut counter: i32 = 0;
    let arraySize: usize = 0;
    for line in buffered.lines() {
        if counter == 0
        {
            let line = String::from(line?);
            arraySize = line.parse().unwrap();
            println!("{}", arraySize);
            counter += 1;
        } 
    }
    arraySize
}
```

Which is a function that sets a const value

```
const ARRAYSIZE: usize = getArraySize();
```

My problem is that I just cannot seem to figure out how to get this line to work

```
let input = File::open(&args[1])?;
```

I tried attaching .expected to it, but nothing happened. I tried everything I could find on Google, but without global variables I can change, I don't know how to get the file such that my function can read it and return arraySize.

Comment: Other than the fact that you need to handle runtime errors (`?` just propagates them, but they need to be handled at some point), you have a deep misunderstanding of what `const` means, as eg. using `File` or `env::args()` in a `const` function makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Please provide a **complete** [mcve].

Comment: The Java equivalent would be putting `throw new CheckedException()` in a function that is not declared as `throws CheckedException`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think of the `?` syntax used here:

```
let input = File::open(&args[1])?;
```

As a shortcut for this (more or less - haven't tested this code):

```
let input = match File::open(&args[1]) {
    Ok(input) => input,
    Err(e) => return Err(e),
};
```

Let's say that `File::open` returns `Result<T, E>` - for the second snippet of code to work, the containing function must return `Result<U, E>` where `T` may or may not be `U`.  If this was not the case, then the `return Err(...)` would be an invalid value to return.

Comment: In your particular code, how can I avoid returning an error? I would just like to deal with it as I would in a try and catch because I want to return a usize in my function.

Comment: @TeenCoder use `match File::open(...)` and then match on `Ok` and `Err`, or `unwrap_or_else`

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it.

Answer (score 2):

> Rust - `?` can only be used in a function that returns `Result`

This is not correct, `?` can be used for any return type that implements [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) trait. You can implement this to your own structure, here is the examples from `std`:

```rust
impl<T> Try for Option<T>
impl<T, E> Try for Result<T, E>
impl<T, E> Try for Poll<Option<Result<T, E>>>
impl<T, E> Try for Poll<Result<T, E>>
```